# How to output the display from an application to a vnc viewer?

Tags: vnc, macintosh, remote-desktop, vlc, programming

How to I write a program on a machine with a high end graphics card and a desired platform so that other computers on a network can view the video output of the program on a separate monitor?

Like running an app on a computer with dual head / dual monitor mode but viewing the app on a separate machine not just a separate monitor?

That is to say how do I choose the output screen as a VideoLAN Client Player (VLC) server connection so anyone on the network can open the stream?

Alternatively how can I use remote desktop connections to map to one background app and not the whole display? Accepting advice in any remote desktop program (example: vnc)

I am interested in advice in any language and any OS: mac, classic mac, windows, linux.

Comment: You mean like OBS Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has developed the [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) technology for network-independent service discovery. It is part of their zero-configuration network concept. It works on USB and also on any local network.

There are bonjour clients (both as library and as tools) for all the OSes you named.